# How to Freeze a Counter when a Condition is Met

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a rock paper scissors game, and I want the counter to freeze at its current state when either the player or the computer reaches five first.
So far, the counter will continue to go up when the buttons are clicked, even though I added a gameOver function. I didn't want to just add a modal because I want to see how this would be solved.
Any tips?

```js
'use strict';
//DOM Elements
const rockDiv = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paperDiv = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissorsDiv = document.querySelector('#scissors');

const userScore = document.getElementById('userScore');
const cpuScore = document.getElementById('compScore');

const restartBtn = document.getElementById('restartBtn');

//Starting Conditions

const ROCK = 'rock';
const PAPER = 'paper';
const SCISSORS = 'scissors';
const options = [ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

//Will update Result Message
const displayMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector('.results').textContent = message;
};
//Computer Choice
const computerPlay = function () {
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
};

const playRound = function (playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  //Use an if/else statement
  if (
    (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper')
  ) {
    playerScore++;
    userScore.innerHTML = playerScore;
    displayMessage(`You won ! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`);
  } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    displayMessage(`It's a tie!`);
  } else {
    computerScore++;
    cpuScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
    displayMessage(
      `You lose ! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`
    );
  }
  const gameOver = function () {
    if (playerScore === 5) {
      displayMessage('Congratulations! You have beat the Machine!');
    } else if (computerScore === 5) {
      displayMessage('The Machine has won.');
    }
    gameOver();
  };
};

//Restarts Game
const restartGame = function () {
  playerScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
  displayMessage("Let's Play");
  userScore.innerHTML = 0;
  cpuScore.innerHTML = 0;
};

//Event Listeners
rockDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let playerSelection = 'rock';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});

paperDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let playerSelection = 'paper';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});

scissorsDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let playerSelection = 'scissors';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});
restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restartGame);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="scoreboard">
        <div id="user-label" class="badge">USER</div>
        <div id="comp-label" class="badge">COMP</div>
        <span id="userScore">0</span>:<span id="compScore">0</span>
      </div>
      <div id="game">
        <p id="rules">Best out of 5 wins!</p>
        <p class="results">Let's Play!</p>
        <div class="choices">
          <div class="options">
            <img
              id="rock"
              class="select"
              src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-rock-skin-type-2.png"
              alt="hand-rock"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options">
            <img
              id="paper"
              class="select"
              src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-side-view.png"
              alt="hand-paper"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="options">
            <img
              id="scissors"
              class="select"
              src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-scissors-skin-type-3.png"
              alt="hand-scissors"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <hr />
      <p>Copyright Morgan O.</p>
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="https://icons8.com/icon/zxChrLiJ6g99/hand-side-view"
        >Hand Side View icon by Icons8</a
      >
    </footer>

    <div class="restartgame">
      <button class="btn btn-restart" id="restartBtn">Play Again</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo?  You only ever call the `gameOver()` function from *within* the `gameOver()` function.  You probably meant to call it after determining the winner for any given round.

Comment: Very nitpicky and tangential to the actual problem, but "Best out of 5 wins" means the first to 3, not first to 5. Or maybe it actually means "play 5 scoreable rounds, and at the end, whoever has more points wins", but that usually implies you stop whenever somebody gets to 3.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Thank you for mentioning that. I went over the directions again, and it's supposed to be the first to achieve five points, so luckily I am in the clear, but I definitely needed to undestand that distinction. IMO, nitpicking is essential in coding. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gameOver` function isn't called properly. I've modified it slightly. Try this

```js
'use strict';
//DOM Elements
const rockDiv = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paperDiv = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissorsDiv = document.querySelector('#scissors');

const userScore = document.getElementById('userScore');
const cpuScore = document.getElementById('compScore');

const restartBtn = document.getElementById('restartBtn');

//Starting Conditions

const ROCK = 'rock';
const PAPER = 'paper';
const SCISSORS = 'scissors';
const options = [ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

//Will update Result Message
const displayMessage = function(message) {
  document.querySelector('.results').textContent = message;
};
//Computer Choice
const computerPlay = function() {
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
};

//Game Over
const gameOver = function() {
  if (playerScore === 5) {
    displayMessage('Congratulations! You have beat the Machine!');
    return true;
  } else if (computerScore === 5) {
    displayMessage('The Machine has won.');
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};


const playRound = function(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (gameOver()) return;
  //Use an if/else statement
  if (
    (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
    (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper')
  ) {
    playerScore++;
    userScore.innerHTML = playerScore;
    displayMessage(`You won ! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`);
  } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    displayMessage(`It's a tie!`);
  } else {
    computerScore++;
    cpuScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
    displayMessage(
      `You lose ! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`
    );
  }
};


//Restarts Game
const restartGame = function() {
  playerScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
  displayMessage("Let's Play");
  userScore.innerHTML = 0;
  cpuScore.innerHTML = 0;
};

//Event Listeners
rockDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let playerSelection = 'rock';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});

paperDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let playerSelection = 'paper';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});

scissorsDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let playerSelection = 'scissors';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});
restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restartGame);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="scoreboard">
      <div id="user-label" class="badge">USER</div>
      <div id="comp-label" class="badge">COMP</div>
      <span id="userScore">0</span>:<span id="compScore">0</span>
    </div>
    <div id="game">
      <p id="rules">Best out of 5 wins!</p>
      <p class="results">Let's Play!</p>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="options">
          <img id="rock" class="select" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-rock-skin-type-2.png" alt="hand-rock" />
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          <img id="paper" class="select" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-side-view.png" alt="hand-paper" />
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          <img id="scissors" class="select" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/hand-scissors-skin-type-3.png" alt="hand-scissors" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <hr />
    <p>Copyright Morgan O.</p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icon/zxChrLiJ6g99/hand-side-view">Hand Side View icon by Icons8</a
      >
    </footer>

    <div class="restartgame">
      <button class="btn btn-restart" id="restartBtn">Play Again</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your input! I finally got it to work! I was stumped for the longest time. I will be sure to make sure that I am calling my functions properly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this block at the end of `playRound` function

```
if(playerScore+computerScore==5) {gameOver()}
```